# PuTTY autologin with custom SSH protocol handler in Windows

Tags: windows, ssh, putty

I'm trying to put an auto login in custom `ssh://` protocol handler registered in the Windows registry.
As soon as PuTTY interface gets open I want to log in automatically.

Is there a way to set in the code below the username and password?
This code below will just open PuTTY, but I have to put by myself the username and password in the PuTTY interface.

Any ideas how to do it or may there is another or better way?

Thx for your support.

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\ssh]
@="URL:ssh Protocol"
"URL Protocol"="ssh://"
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\ssh\shell]
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\ssh\shell\open]
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\ssh\shell\open\command]
@="cmd /V:ON /c set params=%1 && set params=!params:ssh://=! && start \"PuTTY\" \"c:\\Program Files (x86)\\PuTTY\\putty.exe\" \"!params:/=!\""
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

- [`-l` switch](https://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/latest/htmldoc/Chapter3.html#using-cmdline-l) to provide a username;
- [`-pw` switch](https://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/latest/htmldoc/Chapter3.html#using-cmdline-pw) to provide a password.

```
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\ssh\shell\open\command]
@="cmd /V:ON /c set params=%1 && set params=!params:ssh://=! && start \"PuTTY\" \"c:\\Program Files (x86)\\PuTTY\\putty.exe\" \"!params:/=!\" -l username -pw password"
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is PUTTYURL.CMD which handles the full URL as per [RFC1738](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc1738)

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
REM    https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1738  
REM    (<scheme>)://((<user>)?:(<pass>)?)@)?(<host>)(:<port>)?(/<path>)?
FOR /F "delims=/ tokens=1,2" %%A IN ("%1") DO (
    SET scheme=%%A
    SET uphp=%%B
)
FOR /F "delims=@ tokens=1,2" %%A IN ("%uphp%") DO (
    IF "%%B"=="" SET hostport=%%A
    IF NOT "%%B"=="" (
         SET userpass=%%A
         SET hostport=%%B
    )
)
IF NOT "userpass" == "" FOR /F "delims=: tokens=1,2" %%A IN ("%userpass%") DO (
    SET user=-l "%%A"
    IF NOT "%%B"=="" (
        SET pass=-pw "%%B"
        SET pass=!pass:%%2f=/!
        SET pass=!pass:%%2F=/!
        SET pass=!pass:%%3a=:!
        SET pass=!pass:%%3A=:!
        SET pass=!pass:%%40=@!
        SET pass=!pass:%%25=%%!
    )
)
FOR /F "delims=: tokens=1,2" %%A IN ("%hostport%") DO (
    SET host=%%A
    IF NOT "%%B" == "" SET port=-P %%B
)
IF "%scheme%"=="ssh:" START "%1" PUTTY.EXE %user% %pass% %port% %host%
```